# Returning and deallocating linked list node

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am not sure if what being asked of me is even possible.
Say I have the following struct

```
typedef struct node {
int key;
struct node* next;
} sNode;
```

I populate a linked list with these nodes and now I am being asked to implement the following function

```
sNode* removeNode(int key); // removes the node with the matching key, returns it and finally deallocates it
```

I can access the head and the current node from the variables

```
sNode *Head, sNode *Current;
```

My problem is not finding the node and removing it, I simply dont understand how I am supposed to first return the node  and then  deallocate it in the same function.

Only way I can think of is by calling `free(removeNode(key))` instead of `removeNode(key)` but then it would be the caller deallocating, not the function itself, no?

Am I missing something or is this as impossible as it seems to me?

Comment: I think that function `removeNode` should only detach the node from the list (i.e., connect the previous node to the next node). The deallocation of that node should take place outside the function. In other words, you should in fact do exactly what you're concerned with ("it would be the caller deallocating, not the function itself").

Comment: [delete a node](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/)

Comment: @ryyker void deleteNode doesnt return the node

Comment: Given that the function returns a pointer to the node, you cannot `free` the node in the function.

Comment: However, if you were indeed given the requirement to implement a single function which "removes the node with the matching key, returns it and finally deallocates it", then it sounds like your concern is in place (and it also sounds like a mistake in the requirement definition).

Comment: Your analysis is correct. You probably want `removeNode` to _just_ unlink it (but _not_ `free` it). Caller can still operate on the [returned] pointer. When caller is done, a call to (e.g.) `destroyNode` can do the `free` of the node _and_ any internal `free` (e.g. `free(node->string); free(node);`)

Comment: I agree, this is just lazy/errored semantics from the requirements/comment. Once `removeNode` (or any other function) returns, it can't do anymore work. You need to ask whoever gave you this assignment. Returning a pointer to a node, and then having that same function deallocate it does indeed sound impossible to me. And as others have mentioned, makes no sense for this function to deallocate the node, then return a now invalidated pointer to where it used to be. Returning a `bool` indicating if a node with that `key` was found and removed or not makes much more sense.